# oracle 19c: set password of 14 characters and alphanumeric

Tags: oracle

I have created a CBD and a PDB inside this one. And I want to create a user in the PDB with a password of 14 digits and alphanumeric.
I get an error when using alphanumeric and long-length passwords.
The command I am using to create a new PDB is as follows.

```
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE pdb_name ADMIN USER pdb_database_admin_user IDENTIFIED BY pdb_database_admin_user_password  
FILE_NAME_CONVERT = (pdbseed_location, new_pdb_location);
```

The command that you just use to create a CDB is as follows:

```
dbca -silent -createDatabase                                                   \
     -templateName General_Purpose.dbc                                         \
     -gdbname CDB1  -sid  CDB1 -responseFile NO_VALUE     
     -characterSet AL32UTF8                                                    \
     -sysPassword SysPassword1                                                 \
     -systemPassword SysPassword1                                              \
     -createAsContainerDatabase true                                           \
     -databaseType MULTIPURPOSE                                                \
     -memoryMgmtType auto_sga                                                  \
     -totalMemory 2000                                                         \
     -storageType FS                                                           \
     -datafileDestination "${DATA_DIR}"                                        \
     -redoLogFileSize 50                                                       \
     -emConfiguration NONE                                                     \
     -ignorePreReqs
```

Do I have to edit a profile?

Comment: what error are you receiving exactly ?

Comment: Password complexity is generally enforced by a separate stored procedure, which is referenced in the user profile. Are you having an issue _setting_ the password, or _logging in_ with a password you already set?

Answer (score 0):

You say "set password of 14 characters".

But in the sample code you posted, the password is

```
pdb_database_admin_user_password
```

Not sure where the disconnect is; do you not understand that the string in the `IDENTIFIED BY` clause is the password you are creating, or do you have a problem with counting?

If it's the latter, I have a simple solution: don't count. Use the `length()` function instead (even on a free SQL engine online, there are many):

```
select length('pdb_database_admin_user_password') as password_length
from   dual;

PASSWORD_LENGTH
---------------
             32
```

(Of course, if you can count carefully, you don't need a query like this; the count is indeed 32 characters.)

Now, the problem is that passwords are limited to 30 bytes - which means at most 30 characters.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-AA1AA635-1CD5-422E-B8CA-681ED7C253CA

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I found that I can use the "ora12c_verify_function" function. it modifies the default password profile. The passwords should have 8 characters minimum and 1 special character. That function solved my problem.  Thanks
"ALTER PROFILE default LIMIT PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION ora12c_verify_function;".